# Qt Model / View

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I get lost in QDelegate, QAbstractItem, QTreeview..

What i want to archive.

A Treeview where i can add parent items from a dialog thats looks like this:

> Name | QButton | QProgressbar

On those parents i want to drop files from the windows explorer. Those childs should look like this:

> Name | FilePath | pre filled QCombobox

Looks like there is no simple way to do that. Can someone explain what i have to look for in the docs and what would be the correct way to get the GUI i am looking for?

Comment: Start with the [model-view tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html)

Comment: Thanks i can work with the Qt views as long as i can use the standard items for them. But in this case i dont know where to start to get a parent and child item that fits my needs.

Comment: The second step would be to read the [model/view technical reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). There is a detailed section about [delegates](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).